# Regular expression to check whether bracket [containing alphanumeric characters] exists after specific word in string

Tags: php

I need regular expression to check whether square bracket [] containing alphpnumeric characters exists in string.
Bracket should be after `Subject:` word.

`sometext..Subject: Auto Reply Re: Some information, anything [0000] continue with anything`

I have regular expression as 
`preg_match('#\[(.*?)\]#', $text, $match);
print $match[1];`

It should return `0000` as output

Comment: https://3v4l.org/edXT6 correct! What is the problem?

Comment: its not complete regular expression.  Bracket should be after "Subject : ".  How to add condition for "Subject : "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will find "subject" and capture the following contents of a square bracket.

```
$text ="sometext [1111] ..Subject: Auto Reply Re: Some information, anything [0000] continue with anything";

preg_match('#Subject.*?\[(.*?)\]#', $text, $match);
print $match[1]; //0000
```